# BLE support for ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does iphone OS support PASP and PXP profiles for BLE. If yes, are there any documentations or sample applications for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, iphone doesn't support them. You can see a list of bluetooth profile supported by each kind of iphones [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647).